# How do I set up a secure cookie and then read its content?

Tags: python, cookies, tornado

I've been looking at [Tornado's documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/security.html?highlight=cookie) and they way it says secure cookies should be set.

The example in it manages to successfully set the secure cookie, but I cannot read its contents using `get_secure_cookie()` and `get_current_user()` will always return `None`.

Is there something the documentation failed to explain?

I'm trying to access the username stored in the cookie so that when someone tries to send a message in a web-socket chat it rejects the message if the user is not logged in.

**EDIT:**

This is how my classes look:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("user")

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.current_user:
            self.redirect("/login")
            return
        name = tornado.escape.xhtml_escape(self.current_user)
        self.write("Hello, " + name)

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):

    def post(self):
        self.set_secure_cookie("user", self.get_body_argument("username"))
        self.redirect("/")
```

This is the websocket code:

```
   def open(self):
        clients.append(self)
        print(self)

    def on_message(self, message):

        print ("message:"+message)
        username = self.get_current_user()
        print(username)
        if not username:
            self.write_message('{"author":"[SYSTEM]","message":"You are not logged in."}')
        else:
            text = "placeholder"
            message = '{"author":"'+username+'","message":"'+text+'"}'
            for client in clients:
                client.write_message(message)

    def on_close(self):
        clients.remove(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

You always getting None because of:
https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L1084

You need to override your secure methods, and tornado have some examples:
https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=get_current_user

Comment: My BaseHandler class has the following code: 
    `class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get_current_user(self):
           return self.get_secure_cookie("user")` Is this what you mean or are you talking aobut something else?

Comment: Ok, next step, can you read plain signed cookie value with handler.get_cookie('user')?
If you can - your problem with decode_signed_value function:
https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L640

Comment: Normal cookies get set normally, but they present the same problem, I cant access their content. Nor can I access the content of signed cookies with the normal `get_cookie()`